# Character encoding, how do I tell the difference?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, unicode, encoding, utf-8

Characters coming out of my database are encoded differently than the same characters written directly in the source. For exmaple, the word `Permissões` shows a different result when the string is written directly in the HTML, than when the string is output from a db record.

```
# From the source
Addressable::URI.encode("Permissões.pdf") #=> "Permiss%C3%B5es.pdf"

# From the db
Addressable::URI.encode("Permissões.pdf") #=> "Permisso%CC%83es.pdf"
```

The encodings are different. But [my database is set to UTF-8](https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/9c348f62-c1a6-4f09-af1f-2d0541e6ca44/d4607f59b1dfb47c0fd86e6410e592b1), and I am using HTML5. What could be causing this?

[image]

I am unable to download files I upload to S3 because of this issue. I tried to force the encoding `attachment.path.encode("UTF-8")` but that makes no diffrence.

Comment: `'Permissões' != 'Permissões'` Is it a typo?

Comment: @BroiSatse I don't understand what you mean. I copied everything from my terminal as is.

Comment: You have this weird tilde accent or whatever over e in first word and over o in the second.

Comment: @BroiSatse No, the tilde is over the `o` in both, perhaps you having broken UTF-8 support somewhere.

Comment: @BroiSatse I'm afraid I don't understand. Here's a screen shot: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s5/sh/63df9e9b-49a9-4fa3-a89f-e0ab8c1116e6/1fd6374e64abd90ec3c6d08dff3eb926

Comment: I think you're facing a normalization problem somewhere. `"\xcc\x83"` is a [combining-tilde](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=512&utf8=0x) whereas `"\xc3\xb5"` is a simple `õ`.

Comment: @muistooshort thank you. Then how do I go about fixing this? Do I have to change something in my database, or my web server?

Comment: @muistooshort OK. I see I have to use a unicode normalization program...

Comment: @JumbalayaWanton - This is weird. My printscreen:  http://i62.tinypic.com/2ptcens.jpg

Comment: @BroiSatse What browser and OS is that? Your UTF-8 support is broken and probably broken for other [combining marks](http://utf8-chartable.de/unicode-utf8-table.pl?start=768&number=512&utf8=0x) too.

Comment: As far as beating this thing into sense goes, look at the unicode_utils gem, it should have tools for dealing with this sort of nonsense. I'd also recommend using simple IDs for your files and naming them in the headers if necessary. I'd give a proper answer but I'm short on time right now.

Comment: @muistooshort - Ubuntu 14.04, rendered on Firefox 29.0. Looks all right on Chrome though. WTH?

Comment: @muistooshort thank you for pointing me in the right direction. Whenever you can, if you could point me to some literature on naming the files in the header I would appreciate it. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe have a look over here: http://stackoverflow.com/q/93551/479863

Comment: @BroiSatse Maybe send a bug report in to the Ubuntu Firefox people, renders correctly in OSX Firefox.

Comment: Are you sure it is a database problem? If you are using OS X note that if you actually save a file called `Permissões.pdf` (combined letter+accent) the filesystem will do a Unicode normalisation step to decomposed (separate letter and accent). This is a really bad bit of design but we are stuck with it.

Comment: @bobince I'm not sure it is the database. It could be the JavaScript that I am using to prepare and submit the form data (name and path). I use `jquery-fileupload`. When files are added I am able to access a data object that gives me the name and path of the file. It could be here that the characters are getting mangled.

Comment: @muistooshort since I am using Rails, I found `ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode` that has a `normalize()` method. Setting the filename in the headers seems pretty complicated.

Comment: You can put that down as a self-answer and accept that answer. Unicode has lots of interesting little traps like this so it might help someone in the future.

Answer (score 0):

To solve this, since I am using Rails, I used [`ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveSupport/Multibyte/Unicode/normalize) to normalize any unicode characters before they get inserted into the database.

```
before_save do
  self.path = ActiveSupport::Multibyte::Unicode.normalize(path)
end
```